# Java: why progressBar percentage disappears if JOptionPane.showMessageDialog() came first?

Tags: java, swing

I have a strange situation. Here is my code in Java:

```
JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Hello");
progressBar.setValue(100);
```

The progressBar disappears (I mean no color), while still its value is 100.

But if I set the value before the message, then works fine:

```
progressBar.setValue(100);    
JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Hello");
```

Any explanation for this please? Thanks for your expertise.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A `JOptionPane` is a modal dialog, which means that the line of code after the:

```
JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(...)
```

statement is NOT executed until you close the option pane.

You can easily verify this by adding a `System.out.println(...)` statement.

Comment: #camickr, I agree on that but what I mean is that even when JOptionPane.. is closed (clicked OK), still the progressBar is shown empty.

Comment: Well, based on two lines of code its hard to tell what you program is really doing. Post a proper [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/) and maybe someone will be able to help.